# How to create user with High Volume Portal User profile

Tags: community, profile, high-volume-portal

I am setting up communities in my personal org.
But I am not able to create users with High volume Portal Profile.
How to make this profile available for user creation?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add this into the community .THis can be done using administrative settings found under community

Follow these sign boards

[image]

Click on administrative settings

[image]

click on the members and assign high volume portal and if you click manage contact for partner it will ask you to assign this profile to you

[image]